# Radio button in listview not getting checked

Tags: android, listview, checkedtextview

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int position, long arg3) {
                //option1
                list.setItemChecked(position, true);
                //option2
                View v = list.getChildAt(position);
                CheckedTextView checkbox = (CheckedTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text1);
                checkbox.setChecked(true);
```

It appears checked only after I reopen the dialog containing the listview.
I want it to be checked before the dialog is dismissed.
If the dialog is never dismissed, it gets checked.But i need to dismiss the dialog and I need the item to be checked on press

Comment: I think you want to use list instead of reportList in option 2

Comment: call listview.invalidateView();